# mysqldump with WHERE id IN (SELECT ...) yields table "was not locked" error

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have 2 databases, with ~100,000 rows missing from the table `field_collection_item` from `db1`, which I'd like to repair by exporting from `db2`.

My plan to accomplish this was to:

1. identify the missing items by `item_id` in `db2`, exporting the list of `item_id`s.
2. import the `item_id`s into `db1` into a new table `missing_field_collection_item`
3. Using the following mysqldump to pull the data:

   **mysqldump -u USER -pPASS DATABASE --no-create-info --tables field_collection_item --where="item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM missing_field_collection_item);"**

however this gives the error:

```
Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `field_collection_item` WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM missing_field_collection_item);': Table 'missing_field_collection_item' was not locked with LOCK TABLES (1100)
```

I would prefer to do this without making changes to `db2` however it's not strictly necessary, if it turns out the only realistic way to do this is to drop the rows I don't want and then dump without a where clause.

**UPDATE**

I discovered the above works simply by adding `--single-transaction`, which seems to turn off locking. This should be safe since `db2` isn't live, however I'm not confident I understand any side-effects, so I won't accept this as the answer without a second opinion.

Comment: does listing both tables in the `--tables` command work?

Comment: Yes, however then I'd need to parse the dump and exclude the `missing_field_collection_item` inserts. Not particularly difficult but it just seems a bit dirty. Maybe you're right though, it's better the devil you know.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If your tables are MyISAM, the safest, easiest way to handle this is to pass the flag `--lock-all-tables`. If your tables are InnoDB then `--single-transaction` is better.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with --single-transaction too :)

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need a consistency guarantee, you can disable locking without single transaction by adding:

> --lock-tables=false

I use this to do the same thing you're after (dumping subsets of the data) and on replication slaves that I can stop (making it consistent anyway).

An advantage over `--single-transaction` is that you can use/mix non-MVCC-engine tables.