# MYSQLdump not working with SELECT statement in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I've looked around and as far as can tell this should work fine
Im trying to use my sql dump to get a bunch of notes comments, ive had it working with statements such as --no-data and with other variations of WHERE but not this one
I've been doing it in PHP

`mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost DB 
notes_comments --where="notes_comments.note_id IN (SELECT notes.note_id FROM notes WHERE notes_category_id=1 OR notes.datetime_created > '2018-04-30 18:16:15')" > db.sql`

The above statement is the one I want to use but the results have no records in them, db.sql file has it dropping the table if exists and then creating it but has no records in it

However if I use:

`mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost DB 
notes_comments --where="notes_comments.note_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)" > db.sql`

it works and gives an insert statement in db.sql

I've tested the SELECT in the original WHERE and tested it in a WHERE to get me the records I want and it works fine.

Im not sure what the issue is

Edit with extra statments:

`mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost DB notes_comments --where="notes_comments.note_id IN (SELECT notes.note_id FROM notes)" > db.sql`

returns no records again but creates the structure

`mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost DB notes_comments --where="notes_comments.note_id IN (SELECT notes.note_id FROM notes WHERE notes_category_id=1 )" > db.sql`

Also returns no records but creates the structure

`mysqldump --user=root --host=localhost DB notes_comments --where="notes_comments.note_id IN (SELECT notes.note_id FROM notes WHERE notes.datetime_created > '2018-05-01 10:20:29')" > db.sql`

Like the others returns no records but creates the structure

Comment: What is the result you get when you remove the `WHERE notes_category_id=1 OR notes.datetime_created > '2018-04-30 18:16:15'` part? What is the result you get when you remove the `OR notes.datetime_created > '2018-04-30 18:16:15')` part? What is the result when you remove the `notes_category_id=1` part? Please edit your question to include the result of these 3 tests.

Comment: Edited to include those SQL statments, no change in results

Comment: Do you get an error message when running the `mysqldump` command? Is the error message something about not locked tables? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053229/mysqldump-with-where-id-in-select-yields-table-was-not-locked-error about this error

Comment: I havent seen that error as I have been running it with exec in php, the tag was removed from the question but I should have mentioned it in the body sorry, however just run it from cmd and yes its got that error, thank you will look at that thread

Comment: Thank you mate that solved it all for me